# How to implement add_image_size in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, images

I created a plugin and I need to use [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) in it.

I know how it works in the `functions.php` file and for a theme, but how can I implement this in a plugin?

I want new images uploaded by WordPress users to be smaller for mobile screens by

```
add_image_size( 'wp_small', 60, 75, true ); // mobile
```

I read that you need to use `init` or `admin_init` but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Did you finish your plugin yet? And did you release it by any chance? I'm searching for one currently, can't be bothered to code something... :D

Answer (score 6):

Just call this function in the `init` action. This action is fired for both frontend and backend. So it should look like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse4378_add_new_image_size' );
function wpse4378_add_new_image_size() {
    add_image_size( 'wp_small', 60, 75, true ); //mobile
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's better to call it in `after_setup_theme` instead of `init` action:

[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/add_image_size) says you should call `add_image_size` in `functions.php` so the closest [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is `after_setup_theme`. Then you have:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_theme_setup' );
function your_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'wp_small', 60, 75, true ); //mobile
}
```

(Also explained in [user contributed notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/#user-contributed-notes))

Comment: OP asked how to do that from a plugin. Not from functions.php.

Comment: @leymannx This code is meant to be inside a plugin: it's the `after_setup_theme` action that is fired just after functions.php, which is way before `init`.
Inside functions.php this action is nonsense.